# Why is 'S' the 'W'orkspace switcher and 'W' the 'S'cale plugin?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

What is the rational behind these choices of shortcut keys?

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>**S**</kbd>: **W**orkspace switcher
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>**W**</kbd>: **S**cale

I frequently press the wrong one since it seems backwards to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've memorized them as  **W** indow list and **S** witch workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Technically at compiz there are Viewports of only one Workspace. Thereafter you are Switching Viewports.
And besides that, as luisfpg pointed, there are others minemonics for those shortcuts ;-)